# I cant append to my JSON array with Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, parsing

This doesn't seem to work with this line being the issue

`data["Objects"]["Text"].append({"f":"var6", "g":"var7", "h":"var8"})`

This is the entire function

```
def CreateTextJSON(TextObject):
    print("s")
    with open('base.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    data["Objects"]["Text"].append({"f":"var6", "g":"var7", "h":"var8"})

    with open('base.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
```

This is my JSON (base.json)

```
{
    "Objects": [
    {
        "Type": "Menu",
        "Path": "assets/images/mainmenu/mainmenu.png",
        "Name": "MainMenu",
        "X": 0,
        "Y": 0,
        "Width": 1920,
        "Height": 1080,
        "Buttons": [],
        "Text": []
    }]
}
```

Im trying to add to the `[Text]` array but I can't seem to.

Comment: what, *exactly* doesn't work?

Comment: Your example JSON is missing a `{`. You say you can't seem to, but what error message is reported?

Comment: Also, the problem would seem to be that `"Objects"` is not a dictionary, but a list with 1 element, which is the dictionary, so you need `data["Objects"][0]["Text"].append( ...`

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @Grismar "Also, the problem would seem to be that "Objects" is not a dictionary, but a list with 1 element, which is the dictionary, so you need data["Objects"][0]["Text"].append( ..."